# Access takes a long time to open reports

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Database.  When I try to open a report, either in Design view or Regular view, it takes nearly 2 minutes to open.  This is a new behavior (everything was fine last week but after leaving my computer, and the DB, on over the weekend, this started) and even occurs when opening a report that has no data bound to it.  Not sure if this matters, but the DB is split.  This even happens with I try to programmatically open a report, using DoCMD.  I've tried to compact and repair both sides, but this does not seem to help.  Any ideas?

thanks
jason

Comment: Try to change the default printer of Windows. Access reads the information from this when launching a report.

Comment: Interesting.  I do seem to have issues connecting to my printer.  Is there a way to set the default to just PDF output or something that wouldn't rely on the network?

Comment: Well, that seems to be the issue.  Thanks!  If you post this as a response, I will mark it correct.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the first comment.  As that is what the answer was.  It turned out to be a network issue where Access was looking for the default printer, which it couldn't connect to due to the issue with the network.

Comment: Ah! The change is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the default printer of Windows.

Access reads the information from this when launching a report.